# javascript if (expression) syntax

Tags: javascript

On an aspx page in a project I'm working on, I found an expression like this at runtime:

```
if ( (8 10) || (2013 2014))
```

(these numbers are generated dynamically from other functions). I know || is "or" but what does (num1 num2) mean? there are no commas or anything separating them and there doesn't seem to be anything to evaluate. The first two are months and the second two are years which comes from a date picker. Visual Studio flags it as a syntax error but the page runs seemingly OK.

Comment: That's a syntax error. The page has a bug.

Comment: This isn't valid javascript. Is there a macro system or something ? Is the space a real space (i.e. `\u0020`) ?

Comment: yes, a real space. And thanks. I just wanted to be sure. When I single step through it, it goes over each value so "something" seems to work.

Comment: Just confirmed that this code does nothing at all.